# How can I hide the Status/Notification Bar on Android 4.4?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, notification-bar, xposed-framework

I'm trying to replicate Paranoid Android's "Expanded Desktop" with PIE controls (as much as possible) on my Nexus 5. Until PA is actually released, however, I've got to hack it together myself.

So far, I've successfully...

- Hidden the Navbar (Lots of methods work. Editing build.prop still works. In this case, I'm just using a feature in [Cataclysm ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2518660))
- Enabled PIE Controls via [LMT Launcher](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1330150)

The last thing I want to do is...

- Hide (or disable) the Status/Notification Bar

Initial Googling has told me to install a launcher with the option to hide it. However, I rather like the new Search/Launcher hodgepodge thing.

Is anyone aware of a way to hide (or disable) the status bar?

---

*Edit: 2013-12-04*

Now that [Xposed Framework](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1574401) works on Android 4.4, I'm using it with the [GravityBox module](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2554049), which has also been updated to support Android 4.4.

Unfortunately, using GravityBox Expanded Desktop to hide both the Navigation Bar and Status Bar disables the notification drawer - something I certainly don't want.

The PIE controls from LMT are more functional than those from GravityBox, so I'm using LMT PIE controls with GravityBox on expanded desktop until PA is released.